# Sed extract with varying pattern

Tags: bash, sed

My file looks like this:

```
>2011_07_item_1
CCAATACGGGCGCGCAGGCTTTCTATCGCGCGGCCGGCTTCGTCGAGGAC
GGGCGGCGCAAGGATTACTACCGCAGCGGCCAGGGGCGCGAGGACGCGCT
GCTGATGAGCCGCGCGCTGCCATGAGGGAGACACCGATGCCGATCGTCGC
AACCGAGTCGTGGACGCTGGAACTGCCCGAGGAGTGGTCGGCGCAGGAGG
ACGAGGACGTCGTGGTGATCGAGGACGAGGACGGCGTGAGCTGTCTCGAG
ATCTCGGCGCTGGTGCTGGAGAGCGGCGCCGTGGGCGACGAGGATCTGGC
CGAGTTCAGCCGCGATCTTCTCG
>2011_07_item_2
ATATAAACCTTATTCATCGTTTTCAGCCTAATTTTCCATTTAACAGGGAT
GATTTTCGTCAAAATGCTGAGGCTTTACCAAGATTTTCTACCTTGCACCT
TCAGAAAAAAATCATGGCATTTATAGACGAAATTCTCGAGAAACCATCAT
ACGGATGGACGGACGAAAAGGGCAATTTTTACAAACCTTCACCCAAAGAA
CTGATCAAAGAATTTTTCAGTCGCTTGAATGTATTCAAAAACAAAAAGAA
CTGGCTTGCCTTTACTTCATGGGTTTCCATTCTGATCTTATTTCCGTTTT
TCCTTTTGTTTATCTTCAAATACTTT
>2011_07_item_3
...
```

I want to extract ids:

```
2011_07_item_1
2011_07_item_2
2011_07_item_3
```

I was trying to use `sed -n '/>/,/\n/p'` but this doesn't work at all. If I use `sed -n '/>/,/[A-Z]/p'` I get the id and the first line after:

```
>2011_07_item_1
CCAATACGGGCGCGCAGGCTTTCTATCGCGCGGCCGGCTTCGTCGAGGAC
>2011_07_item_2
ATATAAACCTTATTCATCGTTTTCAGCCTAATTTTCCATTTAACAGGGAT
>2011_07_item_3
```

Any ideas why this happens and how to fix it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sed is a line oriented tool; it reads its input line by line and before loading each line into the pattern space, it trims off the trailing `\n`; so, `/\n/` will never match anything.

Do it like this instead:

```
sed -n 's/^>//p'
```

`-n` supresses default output, and `s/^>//p` tries to remove a `>` from beginning of the pattern space; if it succeeds, the resultant line is printed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use grep with -o option:

```
grep -oP '^>\K.*' file.txt
```

Comment: -P (and therefore \K) is an extension, not all greps have it

Comment: Can't remember grep without -P and \K.
Which versions do not have it?

Comment: busybox, toybox, freebsd, solaris, hp-ux are the ones I recall

Comment: It's not a part of [the standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html)

Comment: Ok, but this is not Linux standard, it is opengroup standard for geeks who need a very very small old-style linux.
All actual Linux have this (ubuntu, oraclelinux, clearlinux,amazonlinux,debian, etc)
But thanks for the info, forget about opengroup.

Comment: The question wasn't tagged *linux*, and that standard has nothing to do with Linux kernel.